# How to clone and deploy multiple machines?

Tags: setup, clone, deployment

See what I wanna do is basically make bootable clones or disc images or whatever(let's call it "stuff" for now ) and store many of them in a single big HDD. Then, I wanna use that big HDD and the "stuff" in it to be able to deploy new machines without the hassle of reinstalling Windows and whatnot(i.e. I do not want to restore nor simply clone a same machine, I literally want to use clones to save time during machine set up). Obviously I'd deploy the "stuff" onto an HDD going into a machine that I know the hardware of to avoid driver issues and whatnot. I alos have enough Windows keys to deal with the multiple activations.

I tried using Acronis True Image but it doesn't seem to do what I want(unless idk how to use it properly).

Any advice is welcome thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Good answer from DaveM. I also would like to add [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/) suite. It's one out of the best tool fitting your needs and you should take a look. There are enterprise and home solutions.

Also, as per your question, please make sure to [SYSPREP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302577) your computer before deloyment.

Answer (score 1):

GHOST solution suite, Backup Exec System Recovery, Microsoft System Centre, Altaris... Lots of products to do this.   Can you explain in more detail exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

WDS a builtin service on w28kr2 supports multicasting etc... also deploys vhd's which is real cool!

VHD with the DISM.EXE and DJOIN.EXE priceless!